# How do I delete/remove a push from Bitbucket?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, bitbucket

I pushed on the wrong repo, and now the admin wants me to remove my last push.
I can't just delete the repo.

[image: Screenshot of push on Bitbucket]

How do I remove my push from the repo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the [admin settings](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Administer+a+repository) of each repository, there's a menu item called **Strip commits**:

---

[image: strip commits 1]

---

To delete your complete push, you need to strip the *first* (oldest) revision that you pushed.

Bitbucket will then remove this revision and all its descendants:

---

[image: strip commits 2]

Comment: Can you describe how to find this menu in the 2017 version of Bitbucket? Thanks.

Comment: @AïssaGhouti: I just updated the answer. It's basically the same as before, it's just that the "Settings" link is now somewhere else on the page.

Comment: I can't find it. You seem to have missed step 0.

Comment: For everyone who can't find it now: please note that the question (and my answer) is about **Mercurial** repos on Bitbucket. At the time I wrote this answer, Bitbucket supported Git **and** Mercurial, IIRC they dropped Mercurial support in 2020. Stripping commits is a Mercurial feature, so Git repos don't have the menu item at all. Today, I can't find it either.