# Mercurial and TortoiseHg: How to push a fresh copy without pulling

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

So here's the sitch:
I am working on a Unity game project with a few others. We are using Tortoise with a repo hosted on BitBucket. One of the other people pushed a version with a huge amount of unnecessary files that we had previously deleted. I'd like to revert his push if possible. Ideally, without having to pull what he has pushed because I don't want to spend 20 mins downloading all of these extra files just to get rid of them again.
Is there any way to do this? Is it possible to push my current commit as a fresh copy to the repository?
Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Will [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9631280/5147212) apply to your situation also?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if the files were previously in your project and then deleted, they will be in your local copy of the repo already.  The repo includes all the history for your project. You could see them if you did an "hg update" to a past version which included those files.

That said, to revert the change use BitBucket's web interface:

[How do I delete/remove a push from Bitbucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22976506/how-do-i-delete-remove-a-push-from-bitbucket)